# iOS: Chemical/Molecule Viewer

Tags: ios, graphs

I would love to be able to type something like `acrylamide` into an iOS app and be able to see it's 3D drawing + components + additional info.

What app can do something like this?!

Comment: This? https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/chemio-students-chemical-reference/id700723947?mt=8

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to tell us what price this app should be, and what 'additional info' there should be - not everyone knows stuff about chemicals and molecules!